# Data truncated for column 'profile_pic' at row 1 im mysql

Tags: mysql

ERROR 1265: Data truncated for column 'profile_pic' at row 1

SQL Statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `student`.`student_info` 
CHANGE COLUMN `profile_pic` `profile_pic` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'images/profile.png'
```

ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.

> ERROR 1050: Table 'student_info' already exists

SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `student_info` (
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `profile_pic` varchar(500) DEFAULT 'images/profile.png',
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `password_UNIQUE` (`password`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

this error is flashing when i am setting the value of profile_pic column as not null however if i am not not doing so this error is not occurring can any body please explain me why is this error occurring and how to remove this

Answer (score 1):

Change your Alter query to

```
ALTER TABLE `student`.`student_info` 
CHANGE COLUMN `profile_pic` `profile_pic` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'images/profile.png'
```

In your schema you have previously defined `profile_pic` with `varchar(500)` now you are trying to set it not null but with `varchar(50)` so your column contains the data which is longer than 50 characters therefore you see this truncated error

Comment: still the same problem is coming and my column is empty:(